# Download a VHD which contains Visual Studio + SQL Server 2016

Tags: windows, installation, virtual-machine, converters, iso

Background

I run VMware Workstation to run the following for my dev needs

Win 10 x64 Pro + VS Community 2015 Update 3 + SQL Server 2016 Express

My base machine is clean.

Need / Desire

Win 10 x64 Pro + VS Community 2015 Update 3 + SQL Server 2016 Express => some iso

Explanation

My friends needs the above dev configuration on his **physical** machine. He needs to wipe clean his Win 8.1 machine for this.

I'm wondering if I get convert my vmdk or vmx or vm* to a bootable iso which I can then load on to my usb via rufus so that when I clean install that iso I get presto ...
Win 10 x64 Pro + VS Community 2015 Update 3 + SQL Server 2016 Express on the **physical** machine.

Research

Scouring some people suggested poweriso to convert to vmdk to iso but it did not help.

I found [this](http://vmwstudio.blogspot.in/2010/06/create-bootable-iso-installer-from-your.html) but it is for linux.

Anyone has any other leads or detailed directions?

Self Suggestion

Can I download a vhd from azure marketplace with this or similar configuration?

Comment: This isn't specifically a programming question, it is better asked at superuser

Comment: @davejal Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667389/proper-install-order-for-visual-studio-2010-with-sql-server-2008-and-office-2007?rq=1 specifically a programming question which has been answered and accepted by the community